# SailsJS Session not stored in local MemoryStore

Tags: session, reactjs, sails.js

I am building a react (ES6) application with Webpack in SailsJS.

The problem I came across is that session is not properly handled or stored in Local Memory Store ***IF*** the action is triggered from the frontend

### Setup:

```
// TestAPIController: 
module.exports = {
  create: function(req, res){
    // TODO: Add user authentication piece
    var user = {name: 'test user'};
    req.session.user = user.name;
    req.session.authenticated = true;
    console.log('session:', req.session);
    // req.session.save();
    res.json(req.session);
  },
  echo: function(req, res){
    console.log('session:', req.session);
    return res.json({message:'got it'});
  }
};
```

Policy:

```
TestAPIController: {
  echo : 'sessionAuth'
}
```

Route:

```
'GET /TestAPI/create' : {
  controller: 'TestAPIController',
  action:'create'
},
'GET /TestAPI/echo' : {
  controller: 'TestAPIController',
  action:'echo'
},
```

Front End

```
onClickCreate(e){
  fetch('/TestAPI/create').then( res => res.json());
}

onClickEcho(e){
  fetch('/TestAPI/echo').then(res => res.json());
}
```

MarkUp

```
<li><a onClick={_this.onClickCreate}>Create Test</a></li>
<li><a onClick={_this.onClickEcho}>Echo Test</a></li>
```

---

### Senario A

Click on Create Console Log: [**CORRECT!**]

```
Requested ::  GET /TestAPI/create
session: Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-01-18T20:21:01.069Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true },
  user: 'test user',
  authenticated: true }
```

And Then click on Echo, Console Log: [**WRONG!**]

```
Requested ::  GET /TestAPI/echo
verbose: Sending 403 ("Forbidden") response:
 You are not permitted to perform this action.
```

---

### Senario B

Now go to `http://localhost:3000/TestAPI/create` in the chrome browser's URL

Browser prints the return from the call. and Log:

```
Requested ::  GET /TestAPI/create
session: Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-01-18T20:21:13.645Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true },
  user: 'test user',
  authenticated: true }
```

And then enter `http://localhost:3000/TestAPI/echo` in url address

Browser prints the return from the call [**CORRECT!**]

```
Requested ::  GET /TestAPI/echo
session: Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-01-18T20:25:24.019Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true },
  user: 'test user',
  authenticated: true }
```

---

Maybe there is some fundamental principle I'm not following?
Or maybe there is a better way to control sessions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the solution here guys: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3965